# Skyrim (PC) - Why won't Skyrim download?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

I have inserted the disk, opened setup.exe and it just opens a TextEdit thing with a bunch of numbers, letters and symbols. I'm pretty sure I have the right requirements. My computer is a MacBook 3,1 with OS X 10.6.8. Processor: 2.2 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo. Memory: 2 GB 667 MHz DDR2 SDRAM. Video card: Intel GMA X3100.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: As stated in the answer, (@Ben Did you notice it was a mac? :P) Skyrim doesn't support a Mac. If you **REALLY** want to play it on your Mac, consider Bootcamp or Parallels Desktop. https://www.apple.com/au/support/bootcamp/ and
http://www.parallels.com/

Comment: @FinnRayment tbh I'm not too famliar with the requirements of skyrim/Mac, and I posted that ~the same time the answer was posted. I'll admit to a bad call on this one haha

Comment: @Ben Oo! Sorry, didn't notice that at first. Haha.

Answer (score 8):

### Skyrim does not support Mac OS X

[image: Skyrim]

### Windows Requirements:

System Requirements Min:

- OS: Windows 7/Vista/XP PC (32 or 64bit) Processor: Dual Core 2.0GHz
  or equivalent processor Memory:
- 2GB System RAM   Hard Disk Space: 6GB
  free HDD Space
- Video Card:  Direct X 9.0c compliant video card with
  512 MB of RAM  Sound:
- DirectX compatible sound card

RECOMMENDED:

- Processor: Quad-core Intel or AMD CPU
- Memory: 4GB System RAM  Video
- Card: DirectX 9.0c compatibleNVIDIA or AMD ATI video card with 1GB of
  RAM (Nvidia GeForce GTX 260 or higher; ATI Radeon 4890 or higher)

---

Running Skyrim on Mac OS X

### The Wine Method (legal)

Step1: Download Steam for Mac

Step2: Purchase Skyrim on Steam

Step3: Download [Wineskin](http://wineskin.urgesoftware.com/tiki-index.php?page=Downloads)

Step4: [Download](http://portingteam.com/files/file/7782-skyrim-wineskin-updated-2014/page__st__210) the following wrapper and follow instructions Note: Be sure to update the Engine in the winery. Then change the wrapper to use the new engine. Then update winetricks in the wrapper.

BEFORE you do the wine tricks>"steam">run step.
Using this method you will be able to use all SteamWorkshop Mods for the game and play Dragonborn,Dawnguard and Hearthfire. It is possible to use Nexusmods using this method but it is more complicated. I will post a how to guide as requested.

For wrapper troubleshooting, read the comments section of the wrapper first. Then respond or Pm the porter.

---

### The Bootcamp Method (legal)

Step1: Read [This](http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/), And read [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5628). Here is the [manual](http://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1636/en_US/boot_camp_install-setup_10.8.pdf). Watch this video, skip to 3:00

Step2: [Download](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1638) This (Note: Bootcamp Assistant may provide in Step5)

Step3: Locate Bootcamp Assistant. (Applications/Utilities/Bootcamp Assistant)

Step4: Purchase a copy of [Windows](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/pdp/Windows-8.1/productID.288401200)

Step5: Follow Instructions inside the Assistant (When you come across "save windows support software" watch [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EbWL1UjzAss)

Step6: Purchase a copy of Skyrim, You can use Steam.

There are Pros and Cons to both methods. Figure out what is best for your situation. In theory Bootcamp will offer superior performance as long as your mac is intel based. It also makes nexusmods much easier to manage and use. The downside is the cost of Windows and the partition itself. Wine is free and can use Steamworkshop mods with ease but performance is not as good.

I've played 200+ hours using the wine method. considering switching to the bootcamp method. UPDATE: I just switched to the Bootcamp method. The difference is incredible. I HATE Windows 8.1 as it is the absolute worst operating system ever created. But damn, Skyrim runs flawlessly.

My Specs (I use the Wine Method UPDATE: i now use the bootcamp method and its awesome.)

Processor: 2.5 GHz Intel Core i5

Memory: 12 GB 1333 MHz DDR3

Graphics AMD Radeon HD 6750M 512 MB

Software OS X 10.9.1 (Mavericks)

Minimum requirements

Graphics Card: 512mb

Processor: Dual Core 2.0GHz or equivalent processor

Memory: 2GB System RAM (I recommend 4-6GB of RAM min)

Hard Disk Space: 6GB free HDD Space

Sound: DirectX compatible sound card

OSX 10.9.1 (Mavericks) It really makes a difference.

---

### Ideal setup

Processor: Quad-core Intel or AMD CPU

Memory: 8-12 GB System RAM (If its using a Wineport,Bootcamp runs smoother with less)

Video Card: DirectX 9.0c compatible NVIDIA or AMD ATI video card with 1GB of RAM (Nvidia GeForce GTX 260 or higher; ATI Radeon 4890 or higher)

OSX 10.9.1 (mavericks)

It is highly advised that you upgrade to Mavericks, it's free to do on the apple website. Really smooths out the game. I can play with the above specs on Ultra settings with zero mods.

When i use mods i use High settings with a few custom tweaks.

---

### How to use Nexus Mods (Using the Wine Method)

Step1: Watch this video Use [this](http://download.cnet.com/The-Unarchiver/3000-2250_4-10655313.html).

Step2: Right Click Your Wrapper or Skyrim Shortcut

Step3: Showpackagecontents/drive_c/Programfiles/Steam/SteamApps/Common/Skyrim

Step4: Create the appropriate folders as need for mods, and be sure to keep the

Pathway pure.

I am still trying to figure out how to get SKSE to work, but i feel like i'm close. Update: I am getting help with SKSE and should have a nice tutorial on it soon :D (wine Method)
SKSE Does work with Wine (just a hassle)
SKSE will not work with cider
SKSE works easier with bootcamp

Reference: [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/SkyrimforMac/comments/1vniqb/how_to_play_skyrim_on_mac_a_simple_guide/)

Comment: Great answer! However I did notice a few "Read this" and "download this" comments through your answer. Are they meant to be linked to something? Or are you referring to something in the videos you have provided? Otherwise they don't make much sense.

Comment: Yes, sadly the way I did this it did not work, I am still in a bit of a "pickle" adding all the links into the guide.

Comment: Added all the links, :) Should be working now.

Comment: I have a macbook with specs similar (if not identical — can't tell because they only listed one of the two integrated GPUs), and I can't really recommend it for playing Skyrim even in Bootcamp (the fastest option) unless it's the only computer available. It works, but gives unsatisfying frames per second, in the low teens at best.

Comment: Of course, I do not recommend playing on a laptop either way. But as long as it runs on the OP's iMac he/she should be happy.